# Provide configuration for singleton service in Angular library

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, singleton

I would like to provide a service using `provideIn: 'root'` option in my Angular library (this service is used in consumer apps). However, I also would like to provide some configuration for it (like `forRoot / forChild / withConfig` pattern).

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to provide configuration via creating an injection token. it will be read in the service. The token itself could be configured via providing a new value to it or via creating a helper function that configures it.

Example:

1. Create an injection token inside library and export it:

```
interface Settings {
// some settings
}

// provide default settings if necessary
const defaultSettings: Settings = {
// some settings
};

export const SERVICE_SETTINGS = new InjectionToken<Settings>('service-settings', {providedIn: 'root', factory() {
    return defaultSettings
}})
```

2. Inject those settings into service:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class SomeService {
  settings = inject(SERVICE_SETTINGS);

  // some logic
}
```

3.1. You can provide an injection token value in AppModule (or any other module):

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    // other providers
    {provide: SERVICE_SETTINGS, useValue: {someValue: 1}}
  ]
})
```

3.2. You can also create a helper function that will configure the service. Create this function inside library and export it:

```
export function provideServiceConfiguration(settings: Settings) {
  return makeEnvironmentProviders([
    { provide: SERVICE_SETTINGS, useValue: settings },
  ]);
}
```

Then add this into your `AppModule` or any other module or `bootstrapApplication` or into a sub component tree:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [provideServiceConfiguration(globalOptions)],
})
```